# On changing font-size all other divs positions are getting disturbed

Tags: html, css

I am in big trouble and looking for the workaround for the same.I have a web page in which i have a header and a body section . I have many divs in both sections . 
My question is when i change the font-size of any text in the div , the positions of all the other divs gets changed . Kindly help me out .

**HTML**

```
<div id="generalHeader">
    <div id="divGeneralLayoutContentHeader">
        <div class="col-md-4 defaultBgColor" id="1">
          <div class="eventBoxShadow">Event Name</div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 defaultBgColor" id="2">
          <div class="eventBoxShadow">Club Name</div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 defaultBgColor" id="3">
          <div class="eventBoxShadow">Report Title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="generalBody">
    <div id="divGeneralLayoutContentBody">
        <div class="col-md-4 defaultBgColor" id="11">
          <div class="eventBoxShadow">Hdcp Index</div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 defaultBgColor" id="12">
          <div class="eventBoxShadow">Player Name</div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 defaultBgColor" id="13">
          <div class="eventBoxShadow">Club Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.defaultBgColor{
       min-height: 20px !important;
       border: 1px solid lightgray;
       border-radius: 5px;
       background-color: white;
       text-overflow: clip;
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: is this the only css other than the bootstrap default?

Comment: Yes can you either paste your code in to jsfiddle or give us a little more code I tried creating a fiddle but cant get the results to help you

Comment: Try to add `line-height` if they change in vertical direction. Can't help yo more without fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

property value? Add this value for all DIV in CSS...

If it is not work fine, please paste your code in to jsfiddle or any other....

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please use the comments section. *Answers should not contain questions.*